# Throwing punches while running

Tags: running, boxing

Why do people, particularity boxers, throw punches into the air while running? Is there a reason and is there a name for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing punches in the air is usually called shadow-boxing, sometimes you see Boxers do it in front of a mirror. 
The purpose of shadow boxing is conditioning and practicing technique (if done in front of a mirror).

Shadow boxing during running can have three purposes, first it might be for loosening up muscles that start to teghtening up during running and the second one is simply for conditioning and the third reason might be just practicing throwing punches while moving forward.

Comment: Another important aspect of shadow boxing is added control when you punch and don't meet resistance. One of the most common injuries in any martial art is pulled muscles and extended joints from a strike that's not stopped quickly enough (usually among people coming back after some time off). In a boxing match, your opponent will be duck, and practicing punches that don't hit teaches you to pull back on the punch before something tears.

Comment: Added control - I agree, but I think that it is really hard to control a full force motion without actually connecting with a target - that's why the most important aspect in Boxing punches is to stay loose and not cramped during executing a punch.